# Issue with custom Buttons in Excel Toolbar created in a C# addin

Tags: c#, events, excel-addins, toolbars

I am currently working on a c# addin for Microsoft Excel. I create a ToolBar for this addin with custom Buttons. Everything is working well except one specific behavior:

When you have the excel window opened in small format, let's say half the screen, some of the buttons are hidden behind a menu and are available if you click on a small arrow. The thing is as far as the buttons are in that menu, the Click Event related to them is not caught in the add'in. When you maximize the window and the buttons are completely visible, the event is caught and the process is launched.

Does any one have experienced the same issue or have any kind of advise/clue about the problem ?

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for that problem. I found it on an old post: http://www.officekb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/outlook-prog-addins/2094/OnClick-Event-problem

You actually have to give a Tag to the button in order to be able to catch the Click event. Don't even think about how they implemented their classes :P

thank you for all your answers ;)